# Stop WordPress from cropping images using url parameters

Tags: images, cropping

I've specified some custom image sizes each with a non-default crop position (e.g. top-center). However, when I use `wp_get_attachment_image` and specify `size` to be one that I defined, I get a correctly sized image with an incorrect crop position.

It turns out that the image URI is of the form `https://i1.wp.com/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/myimage.jpg?resize=293%2C160`, even though I definitely have the proper `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/myimage-293x160.jpg` image with correct crop position. Interestingly, though, `wp_get_attachment_metadata` returns the correct, static URI for the given image size.

Why is WordPress deferring to dynamic resizing? Is this somehow prefereble? In any case, how can I disable it?

Comment: Are you on a wp.com site? Or have Jetpack photon turned on? Standard WP doesn't generate images on the fly via URL, the images are just served straight off of the file system

Comment: Turns out that Jetpack came preinstalled, and with Photon enabled. One flick of a toggle switch and my problem is solved. Thanks much! Turn your comment into a question for reputation if you so please.

Comment: Into an *answer haha

Comment: Great answer Tom J Nowell: In my case I had to switch off the option 
"Speed up your site > Serve images from our servers" in the JetPack settings

Answer (score -1):

Please try this plugin for regenerate image thumbnail and then try to display it.[Thumnail regenerate plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)